# Is IEEE 802 a link-layer protocol?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I was examining net/bpf.h (on macOS) and saw this item in the list of link-layer protocols:

```c
#define DLT_IEEE802 6   /* IEEE 802 Networks */
```

My understanding is that IEEE 802 is not a link-layer protocol but a family of standards.  I notice, from Wireshark, that the packets on my Wi-Fi interface have Ethernet (`DLT_EN10MB`) as their link-layer protocol.

What is the IEEE 802 link-layer protocol and when is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DLT_` values *really* refer to the precise form of the link-layer header on packets. `DLT_IEEE802` was used both by some BSD implementations and some Linux libpcaps for 802.5 Token Ring, so it gets grandfathered into some bpf.h implementations

According to Guy Harris on the [tcpdump mailing list](https://seclists.org/tcpdump/2003/q2/185)

Answer (score 0):

The
[Data link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer)
is the second layer of the seven-layer
[OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)
of computer networking.
It's not a protocol - it's only concerned with the transfer of data
between network nodes across the physical layer.

[IEEE 802](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802)
is a family of IEEE standards for local area networks (LAN),
personal area network (PAN), and metropolitan area networks (MAN).

So the true description is that IEEE 802 protocols function
*across* the Data link layer.